# What is the new equivalent of "SubSlice" in this legacy Swift code?

Tags: swift

I was looking over [this legacy Swift code](https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/6d8c9d95f0d812f58be3) implementing Peter Norvig's spellchecker, and came across this block of code:

```
extension Array {
    subscript(r: RangeStart<Int>) -> SubSlice { return self[r.start..<self.endIndex] }
    subscript(r: RangeEnd<Int>) -> SubSlice { return self[self.startIndex..<r.end] }
}
```

How would I rewrite that so `SubSlice` is updated to whatever it should be now?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `ArraySlice<Element>`:

```
struct RangeStart<I: ForwardIndexType> { let start: I }
struct RangeEnd<I: ForwardIndexType> { let end: I }

extension Array {
    subscript(r: RangeStart<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> { return self[r.start..<self.endIndex] }
    subscript(r: RangeEnd<Int>) -> ArraySlice<Element> { return self[self.startIndex..<r.end] }
}

/* example usage */
let foo = Array(0...10)
foo[RangeStart<Int>(start: 5)] // [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
foo[RangeEnd<Int>(end: 6)]     // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let bar = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
bar[RangeStart<Int>(start: 2)] // ["3", "4", "5"]
bar[RangeEnd<Int>(end: 3)]     // ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: I think I see, but when I try to plug the example usage into [the edits function](https://gist.github.com/airspeedswift/6d8c9d95f0d812f58be3#file-spelling-swift-L36)  as `return (word[RangeStart<String>(end: $0)], word[RangeStart<String>(start: $0)])` it still gives me a compiler error.

Comment: @DougSmith The line you link to seems to make use of the `String` extension rather than the `Array` extension that you've asked about above. Also, I've never seen `indices` used like that on a `String` instance. (is `indices` some legacy global function for `CollectionType` objects that is now unavailable?).

Comment: How would I use that? Also `indices` is simply what `.characters` used to be.

Comment: @DougSmith I see. The scope of this question turned out quite a bit more than the first looks of it: seems like a _"legacy-to-current Swift translation project"_ like this is possibly more suitable for stack exchange code review (post you attempt at translating the code), or as separate technical questions here at SO. Or possibly someone can put an effort into it in this thread, and help you out all the way. I need to go to bed myself, however. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Translation of [Peter Norvig's spell checker](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) into Swift.
    // Sample input corpus [here](http://norvig.com/big.txt)

    import Foundation

    extension SequenceType {
      func mapSome<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) -> T?) -> [T] {
          return Array(self.map(transform).filter { $0 != nil }.map { $0! })
      }
    }

    struct SpellingCorrector {

        var knownWords: [String:Int] = [:]

        init?(contentsOfFile file: String) {
            do {
                let text = try String(contentsOfFile: file, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("Loaded file \(file)")
                let words = text.lowercaseString.characters.split { !("a"..."z").contains($0) }.map(String.init)
                print("Split string into \(words.count) words")
                for word in words { self.train(word) }
                print("Trained \(knownWords.count) unique words")
            } catch _ as NSError {
                return nil
            }
        }

        mutating func train(word: String) {
            knownWords[word] = knownWords[word]?.successor() ?? 1
        }

        // Given a word, produce a set of possible alternatives with
        // letters transposed, deleted, replaced or rogue characters inserted
        func edits1(word: String) -> Set<String> {
          if word.isEmpty { return [] }

          let splits = word.characters.indices.map {
              return (word[word.startIndex..<$0], word[$0..<word.endIndex])
          }

          let deletes = splits.map {  (left, right) -> String in
              return left + right.substringFromIndex(right.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
          }

          let transposes = (splits + [(word, "")]).mapSome { (left, right) -> String? in
              if let fst = right.characters.first {
                  let drop1 = right.substringFromIndex(right.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
                  if let snd = String(drop1).characters.first {
                      let drop2 = drop1.substringFromIndex(drop1.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
                      return left + String(snd) + String(fst) + drop2
                  }
              }
              return nil
          }

          let alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

          let replaces = splits.flatMap { left, right in
              alphabet.characters.map {
                  left + String($0) + right.substringFromIndex(right.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
              }
          }

          let inserts = (splits + [(word, "")]).flatMap { left, right -> [String] in
              alphabet.characters.map {
                  return left + String($0) + right
              }
          }

          return Set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)
        }

        func knownEdits2(word: String) -> Set<String>? {
            var known_edits: Set<String> = []
            for edit in edits1(word) {
                if let k = known(edits1(edit)) {
                    known_edits.unionInPlace(k)
                }
            }
            return known_edits.isEmpty ? nil : known_edits
        }

        func known<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == String>(words: S) -> Set<String>? {
            let s = Set(words.filter { self.knownWords.indexForKey($0) != nil })
            return s.isEmpty ? nil : s
        }

        func correct(word: String) -> String {
            let candidates = known([word]) ?? known(edits1(word)) ?? knownEdits2(word)

            return (candidates ?? []).reduce(word, combine: {
                (knownWords[$0] ?? 1) < (knownWords[$1] ?? 1) ? $1 : $0
            })
        }
    }

    let tests1 = ["access": "acess", "accessing": "accesing", "accommodation":
    // .../...
        "whether": "wether", "wrote": "rote wote"]

    let tests2 = ["forbidden": "forbiden", "decisions": "deciscions descisions",
    // .../...
        "together": "togehter", "profits": "proffits"]


    func spelltest(tests: [String:String], bias: Int? = nil, verbose: Bool = false) -> [String:Any]{
        var n = 0, bad = 0, unknown = 0, start = NSDate()

        var checker = SpellingCorrector(contentsOfFile: "big.txt")!

        if let bias = bias {
            for target in tests.keys {
                checker.knownWords[target]! += bias
            }
        }

        for (target, wrongs) in tests {
            let strings = wrongs.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
            for wrong in strings {
                n += 1
                let w = checker.correct(wrong)
                if w != target {
                    bad += 1
                    unknown += (checker.knownWords[target] != nil ? 1 : 0)
                    if verbose {
                        print ("\(wrong) => \(w) (\(checker.knownWords[w])); expected \(target) (\(checker.knownWords[target]))")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let pct = Int(100.0 - 100.0*Double(bad)/Double(n))
        let end = NSDate()
        return ["bad": bad, "n": n, "bias": bias, "pct": pct, "unknown": unknown, "secs": end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start)]
    }

    print(spelltest(tests1, bias: nil, verbose: true))
    print(spelltest(tests2))
```